# Why does the kivy labels text show out of the label?

Tags: python, kivy

I am new to kivy. I want to insert a text into a kivy label at the startup. But the text of the lable shows out of the label as shown below. I can't find a way to fix this. So please give me a solution.
[image]

This is the code of the kv file.

```
<SmoothLabel@Label>
    background_color: (0,0,0,0)
    background_normal: ''
    back_color: (255,255,255,1)
    border_radius: [18]
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (255,255,255,0.3)
        RoundedRectangle:
            size: 50,50
            pos: 100,10
            radius: self.border_radius

<Money_Manager>

    FloatLayout:
        size_hint_y: None
        height:100
        Image:
            source:'image4.png'
            size: self . texture_size
            allow_stretch: True
            keep_ratio: False

        SmoothLabel:
            d: Total_Wealth
            text: "Total_Wealth"
```

This is the code of the python file.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

Builder.load_file('total_wealth.kv')

class Money_Manager(App, FloatLayout):
    def build(self): 
        return self

Money_Manager().run()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `kv` file, you have set the `pos` and `size` of the `RoundedRectangle` to fixed values. You need to set them to the `pos` and `size` of the `Label`. So change this:

```
<SmoothLabel@Label>
    background_color: (0,0,0,0)
    background_normal: ''
    back_color: (255,255,255,1)
    border_radius: [18]
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (255,255,255,0.3)
        RoundedRectangle:
            size: 50,50
            pos: 100,10
            radius: self.border_radius
```

to:

```
<SmoothLabel@Label>
    background_color: (0,0,0,0)
    background_normal: ''
    back_color: (255,255,255,1)
    border_radius: [18]
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (255,255,255,0.3)
        RoundedRectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
            radius: self.border_radius
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer for yours

```
# import kivy module 
import kivy 

# this restricts the kivy version i.e 
# below this kivy version you cannot use the app or software 
kivy.require("1.9.1") 

# base Class of your App inherits from the App class. 
# app:always refers to the instance of your application 
from kivy.app import App 

# if you not import label and use it it through error 
from kivy.uix.label import Label 

# defining the App class 
class MyLabelApp(App): 
    def build(self): 
        # label display the text on screen  
        lbl = Label(text ="Label is Added on screen !!:):)") 
        return lbl 

# creating the object 
label = MyLabelApp() 
# run the window 
label.run()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: This is not an answer. It doesn't use the .kv file, and it doesn't address the problem the user asked about.